# Can somebody explain why the secound output is a2a3 in this code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I have a hard time understanding advanced inheritance concepts, and polymorphism. I want to understand how this works "behind the scenes".
But i don't find tutorials that go in such depth. Where can i learn more abut this?
If giving a tutorial is off-topic(i do not consider this opinion based though, it either goes in-depth on these topics or it does not, but i am not 100% sure) then just explaining the behind the scenes of this code will be enough.

```
// Test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 2) : m_n(n) {}

public:
    int get_n() const { return m_n; }
    void set_n(int n) { m_n = n; }

private:
    int m_n;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(char c = 'a') : m_c(c) {}

public:
    char get_c() const { return m_c; }
    void set_c(char c) { m_c = c; }

private:
    char m_c;
};

class C
    : virtual public A
    , public B
{ };

class D
    : virtual public A
    , public B
{ };

class E
    : public C
    , public D
{ };

int main()
{
    E e;
    C &c = e;
    D &d = e;
    std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n();

    c.set_n(3);
    d.set_c('b');
    std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard leaves the 'behind-the-scenes"  unspecified, but a very common implementation is a "vtable". That should give you a lot of C++-specfic hits in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Defining class A as the  *virtual*  class inherted by class C and D, the members of A becomes the members of C and D. They are finnaly inherited by E. The virtual properties of A has correctly set the members of class A as the members of class E without conflictions. On the other hand, B is not a virtual member of C, and D. After inherited by E. There are C:B::m_c and D:B::m_c in class E. Therefore, changed D:B::m_c to 'b' didn't reflect at C:B::m_c = 'a' which is printed by c.get_c().

To show the difference, you may replace the final part of your code *"c:set_n(3)"* by *"e:set_n(3)"*. It works as well:

```
e.set_n(3);
d.set_c('b');
std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n() << std::endl;
```

But replacing *d.set_c('b')* by *e.set_c('b')* gives compiler error *reguest for member "set_c" ambiguous*. Because there are two  *set_c*  from both class C and class D.

```
c.set_n(3);
e.set_c('b');
std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n() << std::endl;
```